# how to use html agility pack?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I'm new to HTML Agility pack for c# (using .net 2.0 version of this dll).

How can I write this version of jquery but in html agility?

```
var arr = $('.group.section', '#accordion1');
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=1) {
    section = $('h3', $(arr[i])).eq(0);
}
```

Comment: Are you limited to .net 2.0 as well or are you just using that version of the html agility pack?

Comment: I am using this on a sharepoint 2010 platform, which supports 3.5 and lower, and this html agility pack comes in 2.0 or 4.0+, so I figure I need to use the 2.0 version...

Answer (score 1):

[Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) is an addon to HtmlAgilityPack that allows you to use CSS selectors (i.e. what you are referring to as "jquery") .

From the site:

```
var document = htmlDocument.DocumentNode;

// yields: [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll(".content"); 

// yields: [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>,<p>CSS Selector Engine</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll("p");

// yields empty sequence
document.QuerySelectorAll("body>p");

// yields [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>,<p>CSS Selector Engine</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll("body p");

// yields [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll("p:first-child");
```